# Buying gold with a credit card

Tags: united-states, credit-card, gold

Assuming I find a merchant willing to sell gold bullion with a credit card, are there any pitfalls to this besides the additional fee the merchant may choose to add for credit card purchases? Is it legal to buy gold with a credit card? Could the credit card company deem it a cash advance, or is it treated as an ordinary purchase? Or is this a grey area, like purchasing gift cards, where they don't care if you do it a little but will give you a call if you do it a lot?

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that the gold you buy with your credit card could lose value by the time you sell it, perhaps enough to negate the nice credit card points you would earn.

Answer (score 5):

> Could the credit card company deem it a cash advance

Yes. For example, [Amex did that for a while](https://frequentmiler.com/amex-losing-el-al-may-code-coin-bullion-purchases-as-cash-advance/). You should check with your card issuer what they consider as a cash advance.